# Writing a function that returns true when at least 2 characters in 2 groups out of 4 are found

Tags: regex, string, language-agnostic

I'm writing a function that returns true if the argument, which is a string, contains at least 2 characters from at least 2 categories:

- lower case letter
- upper case letter
- digit grammar
- character/everything else

EXAMPLE:

```
abAB => true
aB => false
ab12 => true
1ab2 => true
asdfasdf1 => false
```

I'm working on a regular expression that does this but am having trouble. I've also considered breaking up the regular expressions into multiple if statements and checking individually if at least 2 characters from each group are contained in the string.

For example:

```
comprised = 0
if(string contains *[0-9]*[0-9])
    comprised = comprised+1
if(string contains *[a-b]*[a-b])
    comprised = comprised+1
if(string contains *[A-Z]*[A-Z])
    comprised = comprised+1
if(string contains *[^0-9a-zA-Z]*[^0-9a-zA-Z])
    comprised = comprised+1

if comprised >= 2
    return true
else return false
```

Comment: You might want to clear up your wording so we know for sure whether you are saying "at least 2 characters and they are from 2 categories" or "two characters from each of 2 categories". The opening sentence is a little ambiguous as is whether you need 1 or 2 from a category to count it.

Comment: @LeeMeador I think I'm asking about the first one, so I don't want it to return true if a single character is grabbed from two different groups.

Comment: I don't see the nedd for regex in this case, have a look at this instead: [fiddle](http://rextester.com/PNVXM66645)

Comment: @atomman Cool solution. Why don't you put the code in an answer?

Comment: @LeeMeador Yeah, added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no need for regex in this situation. The java code below shows an alternative way of solving it.

```
public static boolean validate(String s) {
    int[] group = new int[4];
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
        group[getGroupForChar(c)]++;
    }
    int large = 0;
    for (int g : group){
        if (g >= 2)large++;
    }
    return large>=2;
}
private static int getGroupForChar(char c) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c))return 0;
    else if (Character.isUpperCase(c))return 1;
    else if (Character.isDigit(c))return 2;
    return 3;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = new String[]{
        "abAB",
        "aB",
        "ab12",
        "1ab2",
        "asdfasdf1"
    };

    for (String s : tests) {
        System.out.println(s+": "+validate(s));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abAB: true
aB: false
ab12: true
1ab2: true
asdfasdf1: false
```

Site where you can test the code: [fiddle](http://rextester.com/PNVXM66645)

Answer (score 1):

This `.*[a-z].*[a-z].*` will match any string with two lower case characters in it.

This `[a-z]` will match a single lower case character.

Make up 3 regular expressions like the 1st one and apply them to see what's there. If its there, count that category.

After applying it to test, use the 2nd one to remove all characters of that type or replace them with empty strings or some such.

Repeat for upper, lower and digits. Then see if any characters are left, count the 4th category.

If the count is 2 or more, you are good.

*Warning* The string is assumed to have no endline characters in it.